# Does Jooq have a convenient way to paginate queries?

Tags: jooq

It has a very convenient paging query method in QueryDSL.

```java
queryDsl.select(...).from(...).where(...).orderBy(...).offset(0).limit(10).fetchResults();
```

This method automatically performs a count query, and then determines whether further data column queries should be performed based on the number of results.

I would like to know if Jooq also has this quick paging query method that can automatically do the count query for me and the data list query.

Thanks!

Currently I feel there is some tedium when I use Jooq for paging queries. I need to construct the conditions first, do a count query based on the conditions first, and then use the conditions to do a paging query.

```java
var post = Tables.POST;
var postChannel = Tables.POST_CHANNEL;
var postTag = Tables.POST_TAG;

// condition
Condition condition = noCondition();
if (StringUtils.hasText(title)) {
    condition = condition.and(post.TITLE.like("%" + title + "%"));
}
if (StringUtils.hasText(reference)) {
    condition = condition.and(post.REFERENCE.like("%" + title + "%"));
}
if (enabled != null) {
    condition = condition.and(post.ENABLED.eq(enabled));
}
if (publicly != null) {
    condition = condition.and(post.PUBLICLY.eq(enabled));
}
if (createAtStart != null || createAtEnd != null) {
    condition = condition.and(post.CREATE_AT.between(createAtStart == null 
                ? null : createAtStart.atStartOfDay(), 
                createAtEnd == null ? null : createAtEnd.atTime(LocalTime.MAX)));
}
if (channelId != null) {
    condition = condition.and(exists(selectOne().from(postChannel).where(postChannel.POST_ID.eq(post.ID).and(postChannel.CHANNEL_ID.eq(channelId)))));
}
if (tagId != null) {
    condition = condition.and(exists(selectOne().from(postTag).where(postTag.POST_ID.eq(post.ID).and(postTag.TAG_ID.eq(tagId)))));
}

// count
Integer count = ctx.select(count(one())).from(post).where(condition).fetchOne().into(Integer.class);
if (count == 0) {
    return Paged.empty();
}

// list
List<PostDTO> ret = ctx.select(post.ID, post.VERSION,post.PREVIEW, post.REFERENCE, post.PATH, post.KEYWORDS,post.TITLE, post.CREATE_AT, post.CREATE_AT, post.ENABLED, post.PUBLICLY, post.TOC, post.POSTER)
        .from(post)
        .where(condition)
        .orderBy(post.CREATE_AT.desc())
        .offset(page.offset())
        .limit(page.limit())
        .fetch(r -> r.into(PostDTO.class))
        ;

return Paged.of(count, ret);
```

I used to be a heavy user of QueryDSL, and now I want to try Jooq. I may not have converted my mind to many things yet, and I hope to get some guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to know if Jooq also has this quick paging query method that can automatically do the count query for me and the data list query.

I'm not convinced that the convenience in QueryDSL handles all the possible edge cases around calculating total row counts right. See also [jOOQ's stance on pagination, and why a lot of programmers get it wrong](https://blog.jooq.org/why-most-programmers-get-pagination-wrong/).

In any case, in order to replicate the most simple version of what you probably have, just add a [`COUNT(*) OVER()` window function](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/window-functions/) to your query and you're all set. Given the [logical order of operations in SQL](https://blog.jooq.org/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/), window functions will be evaluated *before* pagination, but *after* the `WHERE` clause, so you can use that to get a total row count for your pagination without a second round trip.

Comment: Personally, I like a lot your articles about pagination. Not so long ago, I've implemented the Keyset pagination with Jooq at work, It works really great, both in term of performance and result stability (no doublons when switching pages, etc.).